# ImportError: No module named phpoob.bank

Tags: python, importerror

```
lcl
|
|----|
|----enterprise
|----phpoob
|----|----|
|----|----'bank.py'
|----|
|----'__init__.py'
|----'module.py'
```

this is my file structure

`__init__.py`-->

```
from module import LCLModule
__all__ = ['LCLModule']
```

`module.py`-->

```
from phpoob.bank import something
__all__ = ['LCLModule']
class LCLModule(something):
    _code here_
```

these are my files

while firing the command `python __init__.py` i got following error `ImportError: No module named phpoob.bank` how shold i overcome this error

i also tried it `from .phpoob.bank import something` but it gives `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

what will be solution for it...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using Python 2.x. Folder `phpoob` is not treated as Python module. That's why you can't import `phpoob.bank`.

**Solution #1:** Create empty file `phpoob/__init__.py` After that you will be able to import `phpoob` and import any file inside.

**Solution #2:** Upgrate to Python 3.